# How to position a div underneath an absolute positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `grid-container` that needs to be in the center of the screen:

```
#grid-container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, I need to put another `div` underneath it; when I try to do so, the new `div` shares the same space with `grid-container` instead of being under it.

I understand `position: absolute` makes a div ignore the flow of the document. How would I go about making the new `div` detect `grid-container`?

EDIT: Oops, more information. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="grid-container">

    <div style="text-align:center;" id="grid-settings-container">
        <label contentEditable=true id="size-selector">16</label>
    </div>

    <div id="grid-placeholder"></div>

    <ul id="grid-options">
        <li id="reset" class="button">reset</li>
        <li id="color" class="button">color</li>
        <li id="eraser" class="button">eraser</li>
        <li id="submit" class="button">submit</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div>
    this should be underneath that grid up there
</div>
```

And here's how it is right now:

[image]

Basically, the text should be under the grid

Comment: Can you share a working snippet and an image of required output in order to understand your issue better and solve it? thanks.

Comment: @JustCurious oops my bad! updated it

Comment: Is this all that's on the page? If so, could you set the text as an absolutely positioned element then set bottom: 0?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```css
#grid-container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.grid-bg{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="grid-container">
      test
      <div class="grid-bg"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hey, thank you for the suggestion! that works great for putting content inside the grid; however, I want to place another div under the `grid-container`. I have updated my post so it can be more informative, I am sorry.

Comment: please add your CSS too and show us with a snippet. it would be easier to see the situation

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work if you were to wrap both the grid and the text and center the wrapper instead.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#grid-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="grid-container">
    This is the grid
  </div>
  <div>
      this should be underneath that grid up there
  </div>
</div>
```